# Return column 1 only if column 2 is NULL in all rows with the same column 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is SQL-101 but I can't figure it out nor can I come up with the correct verbiage to find any useful results in web searches.

Example table:

```
id      ext             nr
289979  111-000-1002    529
392959  111-000-1002    NULL
449707  111-000-1002    335
400151  999-555-1212    NULL
456902  999-555-1212    NULL
471001  999-555-1212    NULL
```

I am trying to format a query to return the `ext` if the `nr` on all rows is `NULL` so the query would return `999-555-1212` but not `111-000-1002`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select ext
from t
group by ext
having max(nr) is null;
```

Comment: Geez, I didn't consider the max value angle.  That is perfect.  Thank you!